# Azure - migrating Classic Storage account to ARM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-migrate

I am trying to migrate an Azure classic storage account to ARM. While the process and the prep seems to go alright I was wondering if the new account will still be available the same way. There are no VHDs on in the storage account but a bunch of containters and tables.
Will the "new" storage account still be available in the same fashion? Will I have to reconfigure any of my cloudapps to point at the migrated storage?

-Joe

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the new account the same way before, there is no need to do any reconfigures. I have checked with the Azure storage team before: Your storage account URL and keys will not be changed and even at the period of migrating, your storage service is online. Basically, it is a seamless migration.

To verify this, I created a SAS token(SAS token is generated by access key, it also provided access key will not be modified) and use it to access a .json file every 5 minutes after my classic storage account get started to be migrated to ARM storage account on Azure portal by simple test code below:

```
while (true) {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://andystorage21fge3.blob.core.windows.net/test/test.json?<sas token here>");
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription + "  " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));
                using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine("content: " + responseFromServer);
                }
                response.Close();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Blob service always replies to me as usual even the migration process has completed.

Let me know if you have any other questions :)